# What are good sources to learn about Bootstrap?

Tags: data-mining, statistics, education

I think that Bootstrap can be useful in my work, where we have a lot a variables that we don't know the distribution of it. So, simulations could help.
What are good sources to learn about Bootstrap/other useful simulation methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classic book is by B. Efron who created the technique:

- Bradley Efron; Robert Tibshirani (1994). An Introduction to the Bootstrap. Chapman & Hall/CRC. ISBN 978-0-412-04231-7.